# Error code 1055 from Windows 2012 server manager

Tags: active-directory, windows-server-2008-r2, sssd

there.

I just installed Windows server 2012 on my VM, created an Active Directory, and promoted it to Domain Controller. I just followed the guide for how to create AD and DC, so I can not say that I did the above things correctly.. Though, it seems that I have one DC..

Problem is that Windows server manager shows 1055 error and its detail is

```
The processing of Group Policy failed. Windows could not resolve the computer name. This could be caused by one of more of the following: 
a) Name Resolution failure on the current domain controller. 
b) Active Directory Replication Latency
  (an account created on another domain controller has not replicated to the current domain controller).
```

This error seems to occur when I try to join a realm from Linux. I'm trying to integrate Linux to Windows server.

What am I missing and what do I have to do more to the Windows server for the integration. I thought the error would be caused from the wrong configuration on Linux system, but now I can't find the fault on Linux anymore..

-- Trying the following actions --

1. I can logon to server with "%logonserver%" and see 2 directories, "sysvol" and "netlogon".
2. After I changed the security and sharing, I can get into the sysvol directory. There seems to be {domain} directoy.
3. I used "ipconfig /flushdns" command first, and it shows a html page when I input "gpresult /H {path}". In computer policy, there is Alert "AD / SYSVOL Version Mismatch" and three types of errors are detected, which are 1055, 7320, and 7017. In user policy, there is no error.
4. When I run "nslookup", it says "DNS request timed out. Default server : Unknown / Address : [IP address I set in Network system]
5. Get in [Tools] > [DNS] of Windows Server Manager and press Ok, it says "Access was denied. Would you like to add it anyway?".

Thank you for reading and help me possibly..

Answer (score 0):

Solved. For the other newbies suffering from the similar errors, my problem was DNS setting.
Please get into [DNS] and look through the forward and reverse setting. If the setting are confirmed, then check the password with the "netdom resetpwd" command.

Thank you.